# property of sum of coefs of a chain

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose c is a k+1 chain in U(open set in space R^n), then boundary of c (a k chain) can be expressed as a linear combination of k-cubes, using boundary operator:
$$∂c=∑_ia_ic_i$$, 
where a_i are the coefs.
Above is my understanding so far about relations brought by boundary operator, and now I am asked to show that sum of these coefs is 0, namely:
$$∑_ia_i=0$$,
I don't even see why this is even true. How should I approach this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is $U$ here?

Comment: Edited. It's open set in R^n

Comment: It's been a long time since I've dealt with this, but I'm pretty sure that the it results from the fact that $\partial^2 = 0$.